# Does Mockito mocks classes and functions using Reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, mockito

I've been trying to understand how Mockito mocking works. I've read various responses and there seems to be a conflicting argument whether Mockito uses reflection internally or not.

Here, it clearly says that mockito does not use Reflection:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970810/using-mockito-to-mock-methods-by-reflection#:~:text=Mockito%20is%20a%20really%20well,easy%20to%20read%20and%20understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970810/using-mockito-to-mock-methods-by-reflection#:%7E:text=Mockito%20is%20a%20really%20well,easy%20to%20read%20and%20understand).

On the other hand, the most popular tutorial website says otherwise in the very first line under Mockito:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/mockito_overview.htm

I'm slightly confused with what's true about mocking with Mockito.

Comment: The answer you linked to is commenting on the original question, not on Mockito

Answer (score 0):

Mockito uses the reflection internally. You can check it out this source code also on [Mockito Git Library](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/main/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/configuration/injection/MockInjection.java).