# How to improve mockito default behaviour for Guava Optional?

Tags: java, design-patterns, null, mockito, guava

I started to use [Guava Optional](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) as a part of the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) and would like to improve the use in [Mockito](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockito), where `null` is the default return value for mocked objects. To behave correctly one needs to explicitly tell Mockito to use `Optional.absent()` instead:

```
import org.mockito.*;
import org.testng.*;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import com.google.common.base.Optional;


public class Example {

    @Mock
    private MyObject underTest;

    @Test
    public void testExample() {
        // fails
        // assertNotNull(underTest.get());

        Mockito.when(underTest.get()).thenReturn(Optional.absent());
        Assert.assertNotNull(underTest.get());
    }

    public class MyObject {

        public Optional<Object> get() {
            return Optional.absent();
        }
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

Is there a easy way to improve mockito to automatically return `Optional.absent()` instead of `null` if the actual type is `Optional`?

Comment: Why not just use `Optional.fromNullable()`?

Comment: How shall that solve my problem? Sorry don't get it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to solve it with reflection in `@Before` annotated method, however, I didn't manage to get it working.

Solution you found out can be improved by creating your own static factory that creates mocks with an `OptionalAnswer` and use it instead of default Mockito factory:

```
class MockitoOptional{
    public static <T> T mock(Class<T> classToMock) {
       return Mockito.mock(classToMock, new OptionalAnswer());
    }
}
```

Next step will be to extend a test runner that will use this factory to inject mocks into `@Mock` annotated fields. Search for custom JUnit test runners if you haven't heard of them yet.

Comment: As an alternative to a custom factory or test runner, see my comment on jan's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I got a first shot with the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767437/how-do-i-change-the-default-return-value-for-strings-in-mockito?rq=1) for strings.

```
public class OptionalAnswer extends ReturnsEmptyValues {

    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        Object answer = super.answer(invocation);
        if (answer != null) {
            return answer;
        }
        Class<?> returnType = invocation.getMethod().getReturnType();
        if (returnType == Optional.class) {
            return Optional.absent();
        }
        return null;
    }
}


@Test
public void testExample() {
    MyObject test = mock(MyObject.class, new OptionalAnswer());
    Assert.assertNotNull(test.get());
}
```

Won't get much easier, right?

Comment: Great solution! It can be taken a step further by making this the default behavior. Create a class called `org.mockito.configuration.MockitoConfiguration` that extends `DefaultMockitoConfiguration`.  (Mockito instantiates this class via reflection). Override the `getDefaultAnswer` method to return an instance of your custom `OptionalAnswer`. Now when you create the mock using `mock(MyObject.class)` you'll get the custom answer behavior.

Answer (score -1):

`Mockito.when(underTest.get()).thenReturn(Optional.<Object>absent());`

This is all you need to do. Add the type returned from `underTest.get()` to your `absent()` call. Yes it is supposed to be on that side of the period.

Comment: I don't get the idea of that answer to copy one line from the question(!) and write this is the answer?! Have you even read the question text at all? Really thinking about a downvote here...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to use code tags and `<Object>` which I had put as `<T>` was parsed as mark up so it didn't appear in the actual answer.

Comment: I still don't get what value this unneeded more explicit code should add to my question. Of course one can add the generic type from a static method explicitly, but this is not needed if the type is obvious from content. And the idea of the question is to not need this line at all, i.e. it is _not_ an answer to extend this line with unneeded syntax sugar.

Comment: Literally doesn't compile without it.

Comment: Then I would suggest to switch your compiler. Have you even really tested that or do you simply claim your incorrect statement?