# Mocking builders in JUnit test

Tags: java, junit

Let's say if I have a test that uses builders to construct objects. The problem is that the builder() method in the builder class is static.

Generally, mocking a static method is already an indicator of bad design. However, in the case of builders, the builder() methods are always static. What's the best approach to unit testing methods using builders()? Should the builders be refactored into a separate class to facilitate mocking?

```
class Service {

    private SqsClient sqsClient;
    private String sqsQueueUrl;

    public Service(String sqsQueueUrl) {
        this.sqsClient = SqsClient.builder().build();
        this.sqsQueueUrl = sqsQueueUrl;
    }

    public SqsClient getClient() {
        return this.client;
    }
    public SqsClient setClient(SqsClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public String getSqsQueueUrl() {
        return this.sqsQueueUrl;
    }
    public void setSqsQueueUrl(String sqsQueueUrl) {
        this.sqsQueueUrl = sqsQueueUrl;
    }

    public void onEvent(Activity activity) {
        // How to mock builders in unit test?
        DeleteMessageRequest deleteRequest = DeleteMessageRequest.builder().queueUrl(this.sqsQueueUrl).receiptHandle(activity.getReceiptHandle()).build();
        DeleteMessageResponse deleteMessageResponse = this.sqsClient.deleteMessage(deleteRequest);
    }
}


class ServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void testEvent() {

        String sqsQueueUrl = "http://127.0.0.1";
        String receiptHandle = "asdasd";

        SqsClient sqsClient = EasyMock.mock(SqsClient.class);
        Service service = EasyMock.mock(Service.class);

        // EasyMock expect and replay here.

        service.setClient(sqsClient);
        service.setSqsQueueUrl(sqsQueueUrl);

        Activity activity1 = new Activity();
        activity.setReceiptHandle(receiptHandle);

        service.onEvent(activity);      
    }
}
```

Comment: You may go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501920/how-to-mock-a-builder-with-mockito

Comment: Dependency-inject the `SqsClient`.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- dependency injecting SqsClient doesn't solve the builder() mock problem.

Comment: Yes, it does: You don't use `builder` inside the class, and you can mock the `SqsClient` instance.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike-Ok, that may be the case for SqsClient but what about DeleteMessageRequest? Dependency injecting DeleteMessageRequest doesn't make sense since it is unique per event.